# Angularjs country dropdown directive isolated scope issues

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

```
<country-select country_id="US"></country-select>
<country-select country_id="user.country"></country-select>
<country-select country_id="{{user.country}}"></country-select>

angular.module('picmonic.directives.country-select', [])
.directive('countrySelect', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            country_id: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.countries = [
                {
                    id: "BD",
                    name: "Bangladesh"
                },
                {
                    id: "BE",
                    name: "Belgium"
                },
                {
                    id: "BF",
                    name: "Burkina Faso"
                },
                {
                    id: "BG",
                    name: "Bulgaria"
                },
                {
                    id: "BA",
                    name: "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
                },
                {
                    id: "BB",
                    name: "Barbados"
                },
                {
                    id: "WF",
                    name: "Wallis and Futuna"
                },
                {
                    id: "BL",
                    name: "Saint Bartelemey"
                },
                {
                    id: "BM",
                    name: "Bermuda"
                },
                {
                    id: "BN",
                    name: "Brunei Darussalam"
                },
                {
                    id: "BO",
                    name: "Bolivia"
                },
                {
                    id: "BH",
                    name: "Bahrain"
                },
                {
                    id: "BI",
                    name: "Burundi"
                },
                {
                    id: "BJ",
                    name: "Benin"
                },
                {
                    id: "BT",
                    name: "Bhutan"
                },
                {
                    id: "JM",
                    name: "Jamaica"
                },
                {
                    id: "BV",
                    name: "Bouvet Island"
                },
                {
                    id: "BW",
                    name: "Botswana"
                },
                {
                    id: "WS",
                    name: "Samoa"
                },
                {
                    id: "BR",
                    name: "Brazil"
                },
                {
                    id: "BS",
                    name: "Bahamas"
                },
                {
                    id: "JE",
                    name: "Jersey"
                },
                {
                    id: "BY",
                    name: "Belarus"
                },
                {
                    id: "O1",
                    name: "Other Country"
                },
                {
                    id: "LV",
                    name: "Latvia"
                },
                {
                    id: "RW",
                    name: "Rwanda"
                },
                {
                    id: "RS",
                    name: "Serbia"
                },
                {
                    id: "TL",
                    name: "Timor-Leste"
                },
                {
                    id: "RE",
                    name: "Reunion"
                },
                {
                    id: "LU",
                    name: "Luxembourg"
                },
                {
                    id: "TJ",
                    name: "Tajikistan"
                },
                {
                    id: "RO",
                    name: "Romania"
                },
                {
                    id: "PG",
                    name: "Papua New Guinea"
                },
                {
                    id: "GW",
                    name: "Guinea-Bissau"
                },
                {
                    id: "GU",
                    name: "Guam"
                },
                {
                    id: "GT",
                    name: "Guatemala"
                },
                {
                    id: "GS",
                    name: "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "GR",
                    name: "Greece"
                },
                {
                    id: "GQ",
                    name: "Equatorial Guinea"
                },
                {
                    id: "GP",
                    name: "Guadeloupe"
                },
                {
                    id: "JP",
                    name: "Japan"
                },
                {
                    id: "GY",
                    name: "Guyana"
                },
                {
                    id: "GG",
                    name: "Guernsey"
                },
                {
                    id: "GF",
                    name: "French Guiana"
                },
                {
                    id: "GE",
                    name: "Georgia"
                },
                {
                    id: "GD",
                    name: "Grenada"
                },
                {
                    id: "GB",
                    name: "United Kingdom"
                },
                {
                    id: "GA",
                    name: "Gabon"
                },
                {
                    id: "SV",
                    name: "El Salvador"
                },
                {
                    id: "GN",
                    name: "Guinea"
                },
                {
                    id: "GM",
                    name: "Gambia"
                },
                {
                    id: "GL",
                    name: "Greenland"
                },
                {
                    id: "GI",
                    name: "Gibraltar"
                },
                {
                    id: "GH",
                    name: "Ghana"
                },
                {
                    id: "OM",
                    name: "Oman"
                },
                {
                    id: "TN",
                    name: "Tunisia"
                },
                {
                    id: "JO",
                    name: "Jordan"
                },
                {
                    id: "HR",
                    name: "Croatia"
                },
                {
                    id: "HT",
                    name: "Haiti"
                },
                {
                    id: "HU",
                    name: "Hungary"
                },
                {
                    id: "HK",
                    name: "Hong Kong"
                },
                {
                    id: "HN",
                    name: "Honduras"
                },
                {
                    id: "HM",
                    name: "Heard Island and McDonald Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "VE",
                    name: "Venezuela"
                },
                {
                    id: "PR",
                    name: "Puerto Rico"
                },
                {
                    id: "PS",
                    name: "Palestinian Territory"
                },
                {
                    id: "PW",
                    name: "Palau"
                },
                {
                    id: "PT",
                    name: "Portugal"
                },
                {
                    id: "SJ",
                    name: "Svalbard and Jan Mayen"
                },
                {
                    id: "PY",
                    name: "Paraguay"
                },
                {
                    id: "IQ",
                    name: "Iraq"
                },
                {
                    id: "PA",
                    name: "Panama"
                },
                {
                    id: "PF",
                    name: "French Polynesia"
                },
                {
                    id: "BZ",
                    name: "Belize"
                },
                {
                    id: "PE",
                    name: "Peru"
                },
                {
                    id: "PK",
                    name: "Pakistan"
                },
                {
                    id: "PH",
                    name: "Philippines"
                },
                {
                    id: "PN",
                    name: "Pitcairn"
                },
                {
                    id: "TM",
                    name: "Turkmenistan"
                },
                {
                    id: "PL",
                    name: "Poland"
                },
                {
                    id: "PM",
                    name: "Saint Pierre and Miquelon"
                },
                {
                    id: "ZM",
                    name: "Zambia"
                },
                {
                    id: "EH",
                    name: "Western Sahara"
                },
                {
                    id: "RU",
                    name: "Russian Federation"
                },
                {
                    id: "EE",
                    name: "Estonia"
                },
                {
                    id: "EG",
                    name: "Egypt"
                },
                {
                    id: "TK",
                    name: "Tokelau"
                },
                {
                    id: "ZA",
                    name: "South Africa"
                },
                {
                    id: "EC",
                    name: "Ecuador"
                },
                {
                    id: "IT",
                    name: "Italy"
                },
                {
                    id: "VN",
                    name: "Vietnam"
                },
                {
                    id: "SB",
                    name: "Solomon Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "EU",
                    name: "Europe"
                },
                {
                    id: "ET",
                    name: "Ethiopia"
                },
                {
                    id: "SO",
                    name: "Somalia"
                },
                {
                    id: "ZW",
                    name: "Zimbabwe"
                },
                {
                    id: "SA",
                    name: "Saudi Arabia"
                },
                {
                    id: "ES",
                    name: "Spain"
                },
                {
                    id: "ER",
                    name: "Eritrea"
                },
                {
                    id: "ME",
                    name: "Montenegro"
                },
                {
                    id: "MD",
                    name: "Moldova, Republic of"
                },
                {
                    id: "MG",
                    name: "Madagascar"
                },
                {
                    id: "MF",
                    name: "Saint Martin"
                },
                {
                    id: "MA",
                    name: "Morocco"
                },
                {
                    id: "MC",
                    name: "Monaco"
                },
                {
                    id: "UZ",
                    name: "Uzbekistan"
                },
                {
                    id: "MM",
                    name: "Myanmar"
                },
                {
                    id: "ML",
                    name: "Mali"
                },
                {
                    id: "MO",
                    name: "Macao"
                },
                {
                    id: "MN",
                    name: "Mongolia"
                },
                {
                    id: "MH",
                    name: "Marshall Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "MK",
                    name: "Macedonia"
                },
                {
                    id: "MU",
                    name: "Mauritius"
                },
                {
                    id: "MT",
                    name: "Malta"
                },
                {
                    id: "MW",
                    name: "Malawi"
                },
                {
                    id: "MV",
                    name: "Maldives"
                },
                {
                    id: "MQ",
                    name: "Martinique"
                },
                {
                    id: "MP",
                    name: "Northern Mariana Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "MS",
                    name: "Montserrat"
                },
                {
                    id: "MR",
                    name: "Mauritania"
                },
                {
                    id: "IM",
                    name: "Isle of Man"
                },
                {
                    id: "UG",
                    name: "Uganda"
                },
                {
                    id: "TZ",
                    name: "Tanzania, United Republic of"
                },
                {
                    id: "MY",
                    name: "Malaysia"
                },
                {
                    id: "MX",
                    name: "Mexico"
                },
                {
                    id: "IL",
                    name: "Israel"
                },
                {
                    id: "FR",
                    name: "France"
                },
                {
                    id: "IO",
                    name: "British Indian Ocean Territory"
                },
                {
                    id: "FX",
                    name: "France, Metropolitan"
                },
                {
                    id: "SH",
                    name: "Saint Helena"
                },
                {
                    id: "FI",
                    name: "Finland"
                },
                {
                    id: "FJ",
                    name: "Fiji"
                },
                {
                    id: "FK",
                    name: "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"
                },
                {
                    id: "FM",
                    name: "Micronesia, Federated States of"
                },
                {
                    id: "FO",
                    name: "Faroe Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "NI",
                    name: "Nicaragua"
                },
                {
                    id: "NL",
                    name: "Netherlands"
                },
                {
                    id: "NO",
                    name: "Norway"
                },
                {
                    id: "NA",
                    name: "Namibia"
                },
                {
                    id: "VU",
                    name: "Vanuatu"
                },
                {
                    id: "NC",
                    name: "New Caledonia"
                },
                {
                    id: "NE",
                    name: "Niger"
                },
                {
                    id: "NF",
                    name: "Norfolk Island"
                },
                {
                    id: "NG",
                    name: "Nigeria"
                },
                {
                    id: "NZ",
                    name: "New Zealand"
                },
                {
                    id: "NP",
                    name: "Nepal"
                },
                {
                    id: "NR",
                    name: "Nauru"
                },
                {
                    id: "NU",
                    name: "Niue"
                },
                {
                    id: "CK",
                    name: "Cook Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "CI",
                    name: "Cote d'Ivoire"
                },
                {
                    id: "CH",
                    name: "Switzerland"
                },
                {
                    id: "CO",
                    name: "Colombia"
                },
                {
                    id: "CN",
                    name: "China"
                },
                {
                    id: "CM",
                    name: "Cameroon"
                },
                {
                    id: "CL",
                    name: "Chile"
                },
                {
                    id: "CC",
                    name: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "CA",
                    name: "Canada"
                },
                {
                    id: "CG",
                    name: "Congo"
                },
                {
                    id: "CF",
                    name: "Central African Republic"
                },
                {
                    id: "CD",
                    name: "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the"
                },
                {
                    id: "CZ",
                    name: "Czech Republic"
                },
                {
                    id: "CY",
                    name: "Cyprus"
                },
                {
                    id: "CX",
                    name: "Christmas Island"
                },
                {
                    id: "CR",
                    name: "Costa Rica"
                },
                {
                    id: "CV",
                    name: "Cape Verde"
                },
                {
                    id: "CU",
                    name: "Cuba"
                },
                {
                    id: "SZ",
                    name: "Swaziland"
                },
                {
                    id: "DZ",
                    name: "Algeria"
                },
                {
                    id: "US",
                    name: "United States"
                },
                {
                    id: "UY",
                    name: "Uruguay"
                },
                {
                    id: "YT",
                    name: "Mayotte"
                },
                {
                    id: "UM",
                    name: "United States Minor Outlying Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "LB",
                    name: "Lebanon"
                },
                {
                    id: "LC",
                    name: "Saint Lucia"
                },
                {
                    id: "LA",
                    name: "Lao People's Democratic Republic"
                },
                {
                    id: "TV",
                    name: "Tuvalu"
                },
                {
                    id: "TW",
                    name: "Taiwan"
                },
                {
                    id: "TT",
                    name: "Trinidad and Tobago"
                },
                {
                    id: "TR",
                    name: "Turkey"
                },
                {
                    id: "LK",
                    name: "Sri Lanka"
                },
                {
                    id: "LI",
                    name: "Liechtenstein"
                },
                {
                    id: "A1",
                    name: "Anonymous Proxy"
                },
                {
                    id: "TO",
                    name: "Tonga"
                },
                {
                    id: "LT",
                    name: "Lithuania"
                },
                {
                    id: "A2",
                    name: "Satellite Provider"
                },
                {
                    id: "LR",
                    name: "Liberia"
                },
                {
                    id: "LS",
                    name: "Lesotho"
                },
                {
                    id: "TH",
                    name: "Thailand"
                },
                {
                    id: "TF",
                    name: "French Southern Territories"
                },
                {
                    id: "TG",
                    name: "Togo"
                },
                {
                    id: "TD",
                    name: "Chad"
                },
                {
                    id: "TC",
                    name: "Turks and Caicos Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "LY",
                    name: "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya"
                },
                {
                    id: "VA",
                    name: "Holy See (Vatican City State)"
                },
                {
                    id: "VC",
                    name: "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"
                },
                {
                    id: "AE",
                    name: "United Arab Emirates"
                },
                {
                    id: "AD",
                    name: "Andorra"
                },
                {
                    id: "AG",
                    name: "Antigua and Barbuda"
                },
                {
                    id: "AF",
                    name: "Afghanistan"
                },
                {
                    id: "AI",
                    name: "Anguilla"
                },
                {
                    id: "VI",
                    name: "Virgin Islands, U.S."
                },
                {
                    id: "IS",
                    name: "Iceland"
                },
                {
                    id: "IR",
                    name: "Iran, Islamic Republic of"
                },
                {
                    id: "AM",
                    name: "Armenia"
                },
                {
                    id: "AL",
                    name: "Albania"
                },
                {
                    id: "AO",
                    name: "Angola"
                },
                {
                    id: "AN",
                    name: "Netherlands Antilles"
                },
                {
                    id: "AQ",
                    name: "Antarctica"
                },
                {
                    id: "AP",
                    name: "Asia/Pacific Region"
                },
                {
                    id: "AS",
                    name: "American Samoa"
                },
                {
                    id: "AR",
                    name: "Argentina"
                },
                {
                    id: "AU",
                    name: "Australia"
                },
                {
                    id: "AT",
                    name: "Austria"
                },
                {
                    id: "AW",
                    name: "Aruba"
                },
                {
                    id: "IN",
                    name: "India"
                },
                {
                    id: "AX",
                    name: "Aland Islands"
                },
                {
                    id: "AZ",
                    name: "Azerbaijan"
                },
                {
                    id: "IE",
                    name: "Ireland"
                },
                {
                    id: "ID",
                    name: "Indonesia"
                },
                {
                    id: "UA",
                    name: "Ukraine"
                },
                {
                    id: "QA",
                    name: "Qatar"
                },
                {
                    id: "MZ",
                    name: "Mozambique"
                }
            ];
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<select class="form-control"><option ng-repeat="country in countries | orderBy: \'name\'" ng-selected="country.id == scope.country_id" ng-value="country.id">{{country.name}}</option></select>'
    };
}]);
```

The issue is that the dropdown is not setting the default value to US. I've tried just about everything and can't figure out why it is not setting a default value :/

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I can't access country_id from within my link function. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: These =attr attributes in the scope option of directives are
>   normalized just like directive names. To bind to the attribute in , you'd specify a binding of =bindToThis.

The issue with your code was with the name of the property in the isolated scope, and how you are using it within your template. The quote above says that if you want to use **country_id** attribute on your directive like below:

```
<country-select country_id="US"></country-select>
```

You would specify **countryId** as an attribute in the isolated scope of the directive as following:

```
scope: {
   countryId: '='
}
```

In the template, you just need to use **countryId** which is the property from the isolated scope.

```
template: '<select class="form-control"><option ng-repeat="country in countries | orderBy: \'name\'" ng-selected="country.id == countryId" ng-value="country.id">{{country.name}}</option></select>'
```

And that's it. For more information you could read [Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Also here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hnlaJ638D4IhD3E0LkN5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!